# Reactive dataframe with sortable columns order

Tags: r, jquery-ui, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable

In this shiny app, the user can choose a dataset, this one is displayed and the user can sort the order of the columns (thanks to `shinyjqui`):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(googleVis)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Select a dataset", 
                  choices = c("iris", "mtcars")), 
      uiOutput("sortable")
    ),
    #
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("gvtable")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  Dat <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset, 
           iris = iris, 
           mtcars = mtcars)
  })

  output$sortable <- renderUI({
    jqui_sortabled(
      do.call(function(...) tags$ul(id="list", ...), 
              lapply(colnames(Dat()), function(col) tags$li(col))) 
    )
  })

  output$gvtable <- renderGvis({
    validate(need(input$list_order, message=FALSE))
    if(all(input$list_order[["html"]] %in% names(Dat()))){
      colOrder <- input$list_order[["html"]]
    }else{
      colOrder <- names(Dat())
    }
    gvisTable(Dat()[, colOrder], 
              options = list(
                gvis.editor="Edit me!", 
                page="enable")
    )
  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

This works fine when I run the app: the `iris` dataset is displayed and I can play with the columns order (the list of columns in the sidebar is sortable):

[image]

But then when I choose the other dataset, the list of columns is not sortable. Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by using a different id for the sortable list:

```
  randomID <- eventReactive(Dat(), {
    paste0("list", rpois(1, 1000))
  })

  output$sortable <- renderUI({
    jqui_sortabled(
      do.call(function(...) tags$ul(id=randomID(), ...), 
              lapply(colnames(Dat()), function(col) tags$li(col))) 
    )
  })

  output$gvtable <- renderGvis({
    validate(need(input[[paste0(randomID(), "_order")]], message=FALSE))
    columns <- input[[paste0(randomID(), "_order")]][["html"]]
    if(all(columns %in% names(Dat()))){
      colOrder <- columns
    }else{
      colOrder <- names(Dat())
    }
    gvisTable(Dat()[, colOrder], 
              options = list(
                gvis.editor="Edit me!", 
                page="enable")
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is duo to a bug of `shinyjqui` v0.2.0, which has been fixed in the development version on [Github](https://github.com/Yang-Tang/shinyjqui). You can try that before the newer version is submitted to CRAN.